# Compare 2 populations and find subset in one population similar to other

Tags: r, sampling

I have 2 different populations who are being offered the same product. I am being asked to find a subset of people in one population (on which I have control to run an experiment) who mimic the other in several aspects. My question is, after I determine that these 2 populations are different in each of these aspects (may be using chi square tests, prop test etc..) how can I adjust/get a sample in population A which is similar to population B? Thank you!

Comment: One approach that might help is to cluster your data as a single collective group. After you segment you data, look for the presence of any clusters where members of this cluster are part of both your populations. Conversely, identify groups that distinguish clearly one group for another. The remaining will essentially be a sample that has a degree of commonality.

Comment: How big are the  two populations, the one you want to subset, and the one you want to mimic?

Comment: How many "aspects" are these categorical or numeric (e.g. mean age)?